# How can I reduce the complexity of this expression?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an IIF in my query that says:

```
IIF(ApplicationDate BETWEEN @START and @END
AND convert(varchar,LEFT(AAA.LastName,2)+LEFT(BBB.CITY,2)+BBB.ZIPCode+RIGHT(CCC.SSN,4)) in <list>,THIS,THAT)
```

Where 'list' is 13,000 varchar strings that look like 'MCSM349954987'

When I run this query I get an error message that says "Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them."

Is there a way I can simplify this so my query will run?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: From whence comes `<list>`? Is it a comma-delimited string passed in for use with dynamic SQL that you can split into a one column table with a easily found function? Is it from a table you can query to use with `EXISTS`? Can you create an indexed computed column from `convert(varchar,LEFT(AAA.LastName,2)+LEFT(BBB.CITY,2)+BBB.ZIPCode+RIGHT(CCC.SSN,4))`? Do you know that `varchar` without a length is a bad idea?

Comment: @HABO I copied it from Excel and pasted. The list will not change. I am using MS Server 2012

Comment: there is no IIF function in sql server

Comment: Jeremy, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 has an IIF function. Did I use the wrong tag?

Comment: Try searching for `[tsql] split string`. Once you have a table-valued function (TVF) that will split the string into a table you can either: save the results to a table or use the resulting table in a query. Since "the list will not change" saving it in a table makes sense. You could also split the values to match the fragments (last name, city, ZIP, SSN) that you are trying to match.

Comment: my mistake...you learn something new every day :)

Comment: HABO Would creating a temp table do the trick? I don't have admin rights to create tables but for some reason I can create a temporary table.

Comment: You could use a temporary table, or a table variable, or split it every time within the query, but since it "will not change" why not make the results persistent?

Comment: HABO because I don't have admin rights to create tables. Also, while it will not change, It's data that I'll use for 90 days. I run queries like this and monitor the data for 60-90 days and throw it away and there's a constant pipeline of new data to monitor coming in so I'm trying to figure out how to streamline this going forward

Comment: @bteague see the edit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to figure out how to compare that list... you can do that with a sub query.

First, use `OPENROWSET` to bring in your values from excel into a `TEMP TABLE`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable

SELECT * INTO #tempTable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\yourFolder\yourFile.xlsx',
    [ProductList$]);
```

Now you can use this for your `IN` clause, via a sub-select.

```
SELECT
CASE 
   WHEN ApplicationDate BETWEEN @START and @END
       AND (convert(varchar,LEFT(AAA.LastName,2)+LEFT(BBB.CITY,2)+BBB.ZIPCode+RIGHT(CCC.SSN,4)) in (select * from #tempTable) THEN 'True'
       ELSE 'False'
   END as SomeNewColumn
FROM 
   SomeTable
```